# pcap_pkthdr caplen is 0 in v1.10.3

Tags: pcap

I'm capturing using non-blocking pcap_dispatch and my packet handling function seems to be collecting packets properly and dumping them into the file because I can open the file in Wireshark and see that there are packets. But I cannot seem to track the size since caplen is 0 and the len field is sometimes the same large number (in this case 896715280) or 0. Is there a change that causes this to happen? I think I could calculate the size in version 1.10.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a change that causes this to happen?

Using a version of libpcap built with 32-bit `time_t` values in a program built with 64-bit `time_t` values, as per [this comment on your libpcap issue](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/issues/1249#issuecomment-1856813380).